# How to render the frontpage with two or more queries

Tags: node.js, express, rethinkdb

We have an express server configured in a file called `app.js`, for our crowdfunding platform.

Each page is declared with `app.get` & `res.render`, like this:

```
app.get('/some-page', function (req, res) {
  res.render('some-page', {
    title: 'some-title'
  })
})
```

On our frontpage, we include a query for an amount on one of the crowdfunding campaigns, to show the current status. We do it like this:

```
app.get('/frontpage', function (req, res) {

  Payment.filter({
    projectName: 'testCampaign'
  })

  .sum("amount")
  .execute().then(function (amountPledged) {

    res.render('frontpage', {
      amountPledged: amountPledged / 100,
    })
  })
})
```

**Problem is**, that this structure makes it hard to have two (or more) queries about current campaigns.

**We need** a way to have two (or more) different `amountPledged` on our frontpage at the same time (maybe an `amountPledged` and `amountPledgedSecond`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have two/more queries, then you can just define two/more queries(which will return the promises) and then simply use `promise.all` to get all outputs. If your problem is what I think it is.

You can do it like below:

```
app.get('/frontpage', function (req, res) {

    var p1 = Payment.filter({
      projectName: 'test1Campaign'
    })
    .sum("amount")
    .execute()
    var p2 = Payment.filter({
      projectName: 'test1Campaign'
    })
    .sum("amount")
    .execute()

    Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(values => { 
       // values is an array of resolved value of respective promises
       // You can manipulate the array to get your desired value(like diving all element by 100)
       res.render('frontpage', {
          amountsPledged: values,
       }) 
    });

})
```